# Multiple joins and an array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two tables -

**Table 1**

```
claim bill  render  refer  order  code
32323 323   434     656    233    5d34
```

**Table 2**

```
npi  type  state
323  1     MN
434  2     NY
656  1     NY
233  1     NY
```

How do I write a query to give me this result -

```
code  claim  npi
5d34  32323  656, 233
```

`656` and `233` were selected because their `type` is `1` and their state is `NY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Is this the logic you want?

```
select t1.code, t1.claim,
       (select array_agg(t2.npi)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.npi in (t1.render, t1.refer, t1.order) and
              t2.type = 1 and t2.state = 'NY'
       ) as npi
from table1 t1;
```